# Protractor: wait for angular after page change (async / await)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm running protractor tests for my AngularJS application.

I'm facing the following problem - sometimes, after page was changed, protractor proceed without waiting angular to be initialized. Here is how I perform navigation.

```
beforeAll(async function() {
    await browser.get('#/page-url');
})
```

And time to time, first test in kit fails because it is trying to access some element on page, that does not exist yet, reporter shows me a blank page screenshot.

I tried the following solution from [similar issue answer](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2306)

```
beforeAll(async function() {
    await browser.waitForAngular();
    await browser.get('#/page-url');
})
```

But it does not work for me either. What I'm doing wrong? (AngularJS Version 1.7.2 / Protractor Version 5.4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
describe('your test spec description', async () => {    

    beforeAll( async ()  => {
        await browser.waitForAngular();
        await browser.get('#/page-url');
    });

    it('we can verify that ...', async () => {

        let importantElement = element(by.xxx(''));

        await browser.wait(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(importantElement ),
            SHORT_TIMEOUT_MS, 'element is not present')

        //test code here, your element is ready 

    });
});
```

Comment: good suggestion, though it seems just like a workaround, what if I have lots of different elements? It would be a huge block of code that just waits for elements to appear, there should be another solution

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific conditions but I do not agree on "workaround". If your element is there, I believe it is considered testable (in e2e). I have never heard on any other  way to do similar... :-)

Comment: After some time spent I have to admit that your answer is the only one that did the trick for me. `await browser.get` is being resolved when route change, but not when angular done compile, placing `await browser.waitForAngular` in the code did not prove it's utility

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you placed `waittForAngular()` before the page even opened, so this can be your problem, since there is nothing to wait for yet. Thus try this way

```
beforeAll( async ()  => {
    await browser.get('#/page-url');
    await browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

but sometimes it is not enough, and Hauns answer is applicable in this case. First of all you can wait for as many elements as you want, second, you may watch which element is being populated the last and wait for it or you can wait for the element you want to interact next (no need to wait for all elements).

Comment: I placed it before because this is how protractor team using this method under hood https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/browser.ts I will consider Hauns answer one more time, though it's really odd for me that protractor team did not figure out some elegant way to consider page as fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

With Protractor, you can use the following approach

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Wait for new page url to contain newPageName
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('newPageName'), 10000);
So your code will look something like,

emailEl.sendKeys('username');
passwordEl.sendKeys('pwd');

btnLoginEl.click();

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Wait for new page url to contain efg
ptor.wait(EC.urlContains('efg'), 10000);

expect(ptor.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(url + 'abc#/efg');
```

Note: This may not mean that new page has finished loading and DOM is ready. The subsequent 'expect()' statement will ensure Protractor waits for DOM to be available for test.

Reference: Protractor [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for paying attention, though 1) I'm using async/await approach which seems really different from the regular `Control Flow` 2) How does changed url proves DOM is done? Definitely, not a case for AngularJS application